# Typescript cannot compile latest node js features

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am running nodejs `16.9.0` via the global `n` npm package. I have the latest typescript as a dependency in my project and my TS config is targeting `esnext`

Despite all this, I cannot seem to use the 'new' Error handing feature which was [apparently added to node](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v16.9.0/#error-cause) a while ago.

Compiling my project with `tsc` fails and in VS Code, even after restarting the TS server I get the following error with the test code below

```
const test = new Error('Error one')
new Error('test', { cause: test })
```

> Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)

The same issue happens on the latest node.js `17.2.0`

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

package.json

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.11.12",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  }
```

Although it seems to have been merged into nodejs, [the v8 page](https://v8.dev/features/error-cause) seems to indicate support is still lacking. However I can use other 'modern' features such at the `at()` function on Array prototypes.